# Business schengen visa with confirmed invitation letter + generic business meetings + week of tourism

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

Sorry for the long headline, but my company will be participating in a trade show in Milan, Italy for 2 weeks. I have got the invitation letter from the organizer for the 2 weeks but would like to extend my stay by a further 2 weeks in Milan to follow up on leads/inquiries that I may get during the trade show.

After the trade show, I will also be visiting Frankfurt to visit/stay with one of my good friends and I will be at traveling around Frankfurt for a week.

Post which I also go to Madrid to attend another conference for 2 days. Again post that I will be at leisure for around 3-4 days in Madrid.

I intend to stay for a total of 1.5 to 2 months on a business Schengen visa through the Italian consulate.

My questions are as follows:

1) Is it possible to give generic itinerary details (eg: business meetings, lead follow-ups) in the cover letter for the 2-week extension post the trade show in Milan since I do not have any confirmed invitation letters yet from other businesses yet?

2) Is it ok to give "tourism" details for Frankfurt in the same application? I will receive an invitation letter from my friend in Frankfurt.

3) Same as above but for Madrid post the conference

My personal situation:

1) I have an Indian passport

2) Traveled before to Switzerland in 2017 on Schengen tourism visa already

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

1) Is it possible to give generic itinerary details (eg: business meetings, lead follow-ups) in the cover letter for the 2-week extension post the trade show in Milan since I do not have any confirmed invitation letters yet from other businesses yet?

Yes this is totally fine.

2) Is it ok to give "tourism" details for Frankfurt in the same application? I will receive an invitation letter from my friend in Frankfurt.

Yes this is ok and truthful since you are going on vacation, rule number 1 always be truthful.

3) Same as above but for Madrid post the conference

Yes see above

Answer (score 0):

Just updating here that I applied for my Schengen visa and got it in 5 working days from the Italian consulate in Mumbai!

With a multiple entry 6 month validity for a maximum of 90 days each time.

My application had the same itinerary as mentioned above in my question.

Answer (score -1):

- You need **one** application for **one** trip. That application is made at the consulate of the *main destination* of your trip. This seems to be Italy, considering the trade show.
- Your application should explain the itinerary for your trip. Since you are mixing business and tourism, explain clearly where you are going for business, and which parts in between are tourism.
- Two months is a rather long time for a business trip. Four weeks business, two weeks vacation, two weeks business sounds more logical.